# Quiero saber como usar el operador ternario en este caso del if

Tags: javascript

tengo esta parte de código para validar, pero necesito hacerlo con el operador ternario. Al momento de ponerlo en forma con operador ternario me da un error, si talvez me podrían guiar como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

```
    function getName(){
    let userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    if(userName == ""){
        alert("Debe completar el campo Username");
    }else{
        nameUsers.push(userName);
        document.getElementById('username').value = "";
        setTimeout( function() {location.href = "main.html"; }, 100 );
    }
}
```

cambiando el if por el operador ternario quedaría así:

```
function getName(){
    let userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    userName == "" ? (
        alert("Debe completar el campo Username")
    ) : (
        nameUsers.push(userName);
        document.getElementById('username').value = "";
        setTimeout( function() {location.href = "main.html"; }, 100 );
    );
}
```

pero esto me da un error, les agradecería su ayuda. Buen día.

Comment: La lógica asociada a tu sentencia condicional `if ... else` no se puede intercambiar por el operador ternario de la forma que pretendes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu conversión esta bien, pero al ser ternario en paréntesis, los punto y coma deben ser reemplazados por comas y la linea final sin coma ni punto y coma.

```js
var nameUsers = [];
function getName(){
    let userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    userName == "" ? alert("Debe completar el campo Username") : (
        nameUsers.push(userName),
        document.getElementById('username').value = "",
        setTimeout( function() {/*location.href = "main.html";*/}, 100 )
    );
}
getName();
console.log(nameUsers);
```

```html
<input value="Pedro" id="username" type="text">
```

También observa que removí los paréntesis del TRUE, puesto que solo hay una linea de código.

Otra cosa, puedes usar funciones Globales que reemplacen a esas funciones de JS tan largas.

```js
function GetByID(d){
   return document.getElementById(d);
}
function echo(d){
  console.log(d);
}
//Usandola: 

let userName = GetByID('username').value;
echo(userName);
```

```html
<input value="oscar" id="username" type="text">
```

Comment: muchas gracias, sirvio muy bien tu respuesta.

Comment: Con gusto, me alegra poder ayudar.